# A doubt regarding curvature of space by EM Waves

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, curvature

I did find part of my answer here : [If gravity is a bend in Space-time then what is magnetism?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30477/if-gravity-is-a-bend-in-space-time-then-what-is-magnetism) , but i have a little more to ask.
1)Do they affect time as well? Like gravity near a black hole, does a clock slow down near a superstrong electromagnet?.
2)If an EM wave passes through space, does the curvature at a given point keep fluctuating, i.e: as the wave propagates, do the oscillating fields affect the curvature of space in a different way than static fields?

Comment: Electromagnetic waves are one form of mass-energy, which means that it gravitates, at least according to the theory. In practice there is probably no way to demonstrate this in an experiment.

Comment: Alright @Lelouch, get ready, because this will be a long post.  

You have essentially asked at least 5 different questions. I will attempt to elucidate them here: 1. How does electromagnetic energy curve space-time?

 2.  If Gravity follows GR, why doesn't EM follow its own EM-GR theory(or more properly stated: can we not describe electromagnetism in a formalism similar to GR)? 

3. How is time affected by electromagnetic radiation? 

4. How does space curve in the two case of a static EM field versus a changing EM field? 

5. How are these cases different?

Comment: I am qualified to answer exactly none of these questions.

Comment: i am not qualified to ask any of these questions i guess, at least not in high school. But still, its just an idea i could not let go of. So i ended up asking about it here.

Comment: @CuriousOne Can you please elaborate w.r.t questions 1 and 2?. thanks

Comment: Like I said, it will probably be completely impossible to experimentally test your questions. The strongest magnetic fields that we can produce have next to no impact on the total mass energy of the magnets that produce them and not even the gravitational time dilation due to the rest mass of the magnet can be experimentally tested. As with regards to 2), the theoretical answer is "yes", but, again, this is untestable. Maybe the only system in which this could play a role would be magnetars, but we don't have sufficiently precise models for them, yet.

Comment: To give you an idea about what you are asking, it's probably in a similar category of precision as the question "When a duck lifts off from a lake, does the center of mass of Earth move?". I would have to do some back of the envelope, but my gut feeling is that it's kind of similar order of magnitude. :-)

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/247927/shouldnt-a-photon-traversing-the-vacuum-always-be-associated-with-a-gravitation

Comment: in the Reissner-Nordstrom GR solution, electric charges contribute to the curvature. In fact, it doesn't matter until a general G+EM theory arises. These concepts are internal ( to theories ) and it doesn't make sense to infere any "hard" conclusion starting from the actual tools. A lot of physicists which invent a needle claim that the whole universe was stitched with it.